Touchpad on Acer Predator Helios 18 not working after installing Ubuntu 20.04
The touchpad on my Acer Predator Helius 18 laptop (Model: PH18-72-924C) works with the pre-installed Windows; however, when I install Ubuntu 20.04 myself, the touchpad stopped to work.
I did not disable by (Fn + F7). And xinput command also did not show Touchpad. I saw a similar issue with an older version of Predator Touchpad not working in Acer Predator Helios 300, Ubuntu 18.04: Acer Predator Helios 300 cant find Touchpad Drivers, but in my BIOS, I did not have the "Advanced / Basic" Option. What could I do? Thanks
